# Main method of Java Application is not found

Tags: java, program-entry-point

"Error: Main method not found in class com.oops.inheritance, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
"
    package com.oops;

```
public class inheritance {
    int model_no;
    String name;
    int battery;
    String release;

    public inheritance(int model_no, String name, int battery, String release) {
        super();
        this.model_no = model_no;
        this.name = name;
        this.battery = battery;
        this.release = release;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "inheritance [model_no=" + model_no + ", name=" + name + ", battery=" + battery + ", release=" + release + "]";
    }

}

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        inheritance in = new inheritance(101, "Samsung", 4000, "15 September 2019");
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe `main` must be in a public class. Move it to `inheritance`.

Comment: if I use main method in inheritance function then this error disappears but as soon as use difference class this error arises.

Comment: hello everyone it worked when I created new test class and put main method in it.. but as far as I know we can put two classses on same page. then how?

Comment: You can only have one public class per file. Just get rid of `test` and put the `main` in your existing public class.

Comment: @Carcigenicate You are correct. If the class containing the main method were not `public` then the JVM couldn't use it as an entry point.

Comment: Thanks to you.. what should I do in order to put two classes on same file page

Comment: _"what should I do in order to put two classes on same file page"_ -- that smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why do you need two different classes in the same file?  Putting classes in their own individual files is the way it's typically done (though there are exceptions, of course).

Answer (score 0):

you just need move the main method out of class test, and delete the class test. Then Just run it, you will get correct result